# Error messages next to inputs

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I use simple_form gem for creating forms.

My form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @article, remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <%= f.input :title %>
    <%= f.submit "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

I have some restrictions in my model:

```
validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }
```

But if I submit form without title, there is not a text like "Title is required" next to the title input. How can I add an error text next to the input field?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `remote: true`, this form is submitting via ajax. You have to account for the update to your form in javascript. You can either take out the `remote: true` part or this [explanation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#form-for) can help you get started with handling this in javascript.